# Examples of Finite-index Open Subgroups of Idele Class Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

One of the main theorems in class field theory is that there is a bijection between the finite-index open subgroups of the idele class group of a number field field $K$ and the abelian extensions of $K$. I was wondering where I could find examples and explicit computations of such abelian extensions from finite open subgroups of $\mathbb{I}_K$.

Comment: You might be interested in the finite-index subgroups $C_K^m \leq C_K$ (with quotient being called "ray class groups"), corresponding to the so-called ray class fields $K^m$, which are finite abelian extensions of $K$. Typically, when $K = \Bbb Q$, you get $K^m = \Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$.